# Issue with displaying banner ads Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, admob, tableview

I have an issue while displaying BannerAds for 1st and every 5th row. While displaying data, first row is replaced with banner ads and every 5th row data is replaced with banner ads...How to overcome this. Following is what i have tried.TIA

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger n;
    n= [array count];
    return n;
}

- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0) {
        //configure ad cell

        for(UIView* view in cell.contentView.subviews) {
            if([view isKindOfClass:[GADBannerView class]]) {
                [view removeFromSuperview];
            }
        }
else
{
 Title.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",[dict objectForKey:@"Name"]];
}
return cell;
}

- (CGFloat)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView heightForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

    if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0)
        return 60;
    else
        return 153;
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to increase the number of cells you return in `numberOfRowsInSection` and account for the added rows in `cellForRowAt`

The number of advertisements will be 1 + n/5 (The first row and then every 5th row), so the number of cells in your table will be `n + n/5 + 1`

```
- (NSInteger)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView numberOfRowsInSection:(NSInteger)section
{
    NSInteger n;
    n= [array count];
    return n/5 + n + 1;
}
```

Now, some of the cells you need to return from `cellForRowAt` will be ads and you will need to account for this when accessing your data array.  The index you need is the row number - the number of advertisement rows that have come before it.  This is index/5 + 1 (The first row and every 5 rows).

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)aTableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.row % 5 == 0) {
        AdCell *cell = (AdCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"Ad" forIndexPath: indexPath];
        ...
        NSLog(@"Showing an ad at row %ld",indexPath.row);
        return cell;
    else
    {
        NSInteger index = indexPath.row - indexPath.row/5 - 1;
        NSDictionary *dict = myArray[index];
        NormalCell *cell = (NormalCell *)[tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:"Normal" forIndexPath: indexPath];
        cell.title.text=[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ ",dict["Name"]];
        NSLog(@"Showing a normal row at row %ld (data from element %ld of array)",indexPath.row,index);
        return cell;
   }
}
```

Comment: Still the 1st row and every 5th row data is not displaying. I used the same code u wrote

Comment: Hmm.  I have added some logging to my answer; Let me know what output you get, but I am pretty sure my calculations are correct.

Comment: I Checked the entire code, added this line extra 
NSDictionary *dict = [array objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];. and i removed this. Now works perfect. Thank you

Comment: That won’t be correct unless your array includes rows for the ads

Comment: NSInteger index = indexPath.row - indexPath.row/5 - 1; (for 5th row), if i want to add the ad for every 8th row also, could you please tell me the logic for both 5th and 8th row in cellforrowatindexpath

Comment: `if indexPath.row % 5 == 0 || indexPath.row % 8 == 0` - You will need to adjust your `numberOfRows` return value too.

Comment: i have done that, but what to do in cellforrowatindexpath else condition for every 5th row we are using NSInteger index = indexPath.row - indexPath.row/5 - 1; (for 5th row) and for 8th row what to use. Could you please edit your answer.

Comment: `index = indexPath.row - indexPath.row/5 - indexPath.row/8 - 1;`